# Raspberry pi2 can't boot from sdcard

Tags: pi-2, buildroot

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and I created a Linux distribution using `buildroot`. It generated an `sdcard.img` file. I tried to format my 8 GB SD card and flashing the `sdcard.img` on it using:

```
sudo dd if=~/buildroot/output/images/sdcard.img of=/dev/sdb
```

When I put the SD card in my Raspberry Pi and I put the power cable the ACT blink 2 times.

I don't understand. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

2 flashes mean the SD card cannot be read. Have you verified that your command really flashed the correct device? Have you verified that your SD card is okay? Have you verified if the image is properly flashed on the SD card?

Maybe your image simply does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have formatted the SD Card properly. I personally use the creatively named "SDFormatter" (blue SD Card logo) to format the cards first.

Comment: He's using `sudo` and `dd` at the same time. Looks like he's using Linux. As far as I know, SDFormatter is Windows-only.

Comment: @PandaLion98 I'm pretty sure you can use `dd` on a mac, which is what I use SDFormatter on.

Answer (score -1):

I used ImageWriter and I reformated the sdcard and the raspberrypi booted very well.